# Merging Dask dataframes imported from csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, dask

I need to to import large datasets and merge them. I know there other questions similar to this but I could not find an answer specific to my problem. It appears that with `dask` I was able to read the large datasets into a dataframe but I could not merge it with another dataframe.

```python
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

#I have to do this with dask since with pandas I get mem issue and kills the python
ps = dd.read_csv('*.dsv',sep='|',low_memory=False)
mx = dd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='|',low_memory=False)

# this is where I get the error
mg = pd.merge(ps,mx,left_on='ACTIVITY_ID',right_on='WONUM')

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
```

It is obvious that it cannot merge the dask dataframe with pandas dataframe but how else can I do this? can I use pySpark or any other methods?

Comment: I don't know much about dask but I think you just need `dd.merge()` rather than `pd.merge()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JohnE is right - Dask dataframes have a [merge](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge) method, which (not coincidentally) is very similar to the [pandas one](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html); so, since you seem to need an inner merge, you should simply do:

```python
mg = ps.merge(mx,left_on='ACTIVITY_ID',right_on='WONUM') # how='inner' by default, just as in pandas
```

The Dask `from_pandas` [method](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_pandas) might also be useful, in case you want to convert the Dask dataframes to pandas ones.